# Defining different font size for same element

Tags: html, css

I would like to use an embedded font along side Arial as a substitute. The embedded font requires a much larger font-size.

How can I make sure that Arial displays at 15pt, and Bebas displays at 20pt, for the same element. (For the same piece of text)

Thanks!

*Let me explain further:

I have a string of text. I want it to display as Bebas or Arial. When Arial is loaded as a substitute, it needs to have a different font-size and weight, as sharing the font-size doesn't work well for these fonts (Bebas is small).

Comment: If you use an “embedded” (downloadable, Web) font, then it will be used unless the browser has been told not to use such fonts or some user setting causes that as a side effect. So taking precautions against such cases might be pointless. Regarding fallback fonts, they should be similar to the primary font, so if you need to change the size substantially, you should really use other fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a script like [FontChecker](https://github.com/darkwing/FontChecker) to check if a font is available. It relies on [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) and gets called like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
  var fc = new FontChecker();
  if (!fc.check('Bebas')) {
    $$('.someclass').setStyles({'font-size': '15pt'});
  }
});
```

If *Bebas* isn't available, it sets the font size for all elements with class *someclass* to 15pt.

Your CSS file:

```
.someclass {
  font-family:Bebas,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
}
```

If you don't use MooTools, maybe there's a similar script for other libraries or vanilla JS (=plain JS without libraries). Or just rewrite it, [it's quite short](https://github.com/darkwing/FontChecker/blob/master/Source/FontChecker.js).

**edit:**

Some other scripts (I don't know them, I only use FontChecker):

- jQuery: http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/
- Vanilla: http://www.samclarke.com/2013/06/javascript-is-font-available/
- Another vanilla: http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Comment: FontChecker is a kludge that only compares widths of a piece of text in different fonts. To me, it gives a false positive (Bebas available, when it in fact isn’t).